# Can I checkout a tree object in git?

Tags: git

I have lost the commit object in a corrupt repository, but there are still some files and the tree object:

```
$ git fsck                                                
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
dangling blob 031be26142ed97da216fb7d79d16a0b0efdf0d71
dangling blob 4b2be7dfef082c2e247be52e6d78600af7b6dd40
dangling tree 4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904
dangling blob ccbb1056cb4e744f9a4b44a439fa036f6a3d7cbe
dangling blob 10bfbc3c1fa10e08cd6a783565f00e7324f61fe5
dangling blob 9b529957be714fef304c4e8161fe6cd138510e98
dangling blob dd5b54882d0b74db99c8a7fbba703d528dc559b9
```

Is there a way to check out that tree object?

I guess there could be a way to rebuild the commit object with a dummy commit string and check that out.

```
git cat-file -p tree-sha1
```

Comment: Does `git checkout 4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904` work for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this happens often, or if you will need to switch back and forth from other commits, you can create a new commit object that points to this tree, and then create a new branch that points to it for convenience:

```
git commit-tree <<treeid>>
<<type a commit message>>
^D
<<this will produce a hash for the new commit object>>
git branch newbranch <<newcommithash>>
```

Then you should be able to just `git checkout newbranch` whenever you need to...

Comment: Both this and @sehe's answer are perfect, but this one is more practical if what I want is restoring the state to the repository.

Answer (score 6):

If you `git checkout 4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904 .` (the dot for a path name is important, otherwise git will interpret it as a branch switch operation and refuse) it will update all of the files in both the working directory *and* the index to match the state of 4b825d... (that is, `git diff` will show nothing, `git diff --staged` will show a lot of changes, and `git status` will show a lot of M). You can inspect the state of the files that way.

If you have a guess at a relevant parent commit, you can

```
git checkout -b recover relevant_parent
git checkout 4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904 .
git commit -m "Recovered this thing that git fsck told me about"
```

to give it a commit and a branch to address it by.

Comment: Neat. I didn't know `git checkout` could take a tree id instead of a commit-ish. Having a play with this

Comment: Strange. Doesn't work for me:
```
> git init
> "Test" | git hash-object -w --stdin 
[abcd...]
> git update-index --add --cacheinfo 100644 abcd... test.txt
> git write-tree
[efg0...]
> git checkout efg0...
[fatal: Cannot switch branch to a non-commit 'efg0...']
```

Comment: @AxD did you forget the dot?

Comment: I had few changes(10 changes max) on my tree, after using `git read-tree XXXX`, 7k+ changes on git.

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
git read-tree 4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904
```

or somewhat cleaner

```
git read-tree --prefix=rescue --index-output=/tmp/rescue.index b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904
```

to have it put in a subfolder (rescue).

Be sure to check what the tree refers to, it might not be the repository root path:

Comment: X-Ref: [How do I "extract" a tree-ish to a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72521247/367456)