# Why does `git checkout` produce the error `Invalid argument` when hash of the tree is used

Tags: git

I'm trying to create a git tree and check it out without using any high-level commands and commit objects. So I initialized git and create two blobs:

```
$ git init

$ echo ‘f1’ | git hash-object -w --stdin
8e1e71d5ce34c01b6fe83bc5051545f2918c8c2b

$ echo ‘f2’ | git hash-object -w --stdin
9de77c18733ab8009a956c25e28c85fe203a17d7
```

Now I'm creating a tree using `mktree`:

```
$ echo -e 
    "100644 blob 8e1e71d5ce34c01b6fe83bc5051545f2918c8c2b\tf1.txt" 
    "100644 blob 9de77c18733ab8009a956c25e28c85fe203a17d7\tf2.txt" 
    | git mktree
bf9571850c4570cd36ffa426343b81364a855911
```

Which correctly returns me the git tree hash. Now I want to check it out. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17603805/2545680) I can simply do it like this:

```
$ git checkout bf9571850c4570cd36ffa426343b81364a855911 .
```

But it produces the error:

```
error: unable to create file f1.txt 100644 blob 9de77c18733ab8009a956c25e28c85fe203a17d7        f2.txt (Invalid argument)
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: I did exactly what you did, without any errors

Comment: Was this an empty directory to begin with?

Comment: Also, do you have the proper permissions to be writing to this directory?

Comment: Perhaps you are above the maximum path length for windows: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14811991/git-checkout-error-unable-to-create-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's something slightly wonky in your instructions, because if I *retype*:

```
$ echo 'f1' | git hash-object -w --stdin
```

I get the same hash:

```
8e1e71d5ce34c01b6fe83bc5051545f2918c8c2b
```

but if I try to cut and paste them, I get something very different.  This is because something (I'm not sure what) has damaged the single quotes: yours are actually Unicode U+2018 characters, or [LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2018/index.htm).

Anyway, as a result I was not quite sure what to do with your *third* `echo` command, but if I assume it's undamaged, it's actually sending:

```
100644 blob 8e1e71d5ce34c01b6fe83bc5051545f2918c8c2b\tf1.txt 100644 blob 9de77c18733ab8009a956c25e28c85fe203a17d7\tf2.txt
```

(where each `\t` represents a literal tab character) to `git mktree`, which will make a tree with *one* entry.  Trying that gives me:

```
$ printf "100644 blob 8e1e71d5ce34c01b6fe83bc5051545f2918c8c2b\tf1.txt 100644 blob 9de77c18733ab8009a956c25e28c85fe203a17d7\tf2.txt\n" | git mktree
bf9571850c4570cd36ffa426343b81364a855911
```

which has the same tree-hash, and:

```
$ git cat-file -p bf9571850
100644 blob 8e1e71d5ce34c01b6fe83bc5051545f2918c8c2b    "f1.txt 100644 blob 9de77c18733ab8009a956c25e28c85fe203a17d7\tf2.txt"
```

(I've left a raw tab in this stackoverflow input, which is a little bit tricky but works with cut-and-paste on a Mac).

Checking out that tree into the current directory will attempt to create a file named `f1.txt 100644 blob 9de77c18733ab8009a956c25e28c85fe203a17d7\tf2.txt` (with embedded tab in the name) as one should expect.  Presumably your host OS (Windows?) refuses such file names.

Presumably, what you wanted was to print *two* lines into `git mktree`, one each for the `f1` and `f2` files.  The `printf` command is probably a better way to do that:

```
$ printf '%s %s %s\t%s\n' \
> 100644 blob 8e1e71d5ce34c01b6fe83bc5051545f2918c8c2b f1.txt \
> 100644 blob 9de77c18733ab8009a956c25e28c85fe203a17d7 f2.txt |
> git mktree
97da1d249d1b56762add1fb35096a46544416c7f
$ git checkout 97da1 -- .
$ ls
f1.txt  f2.txt
```

Comment: yeah, I wanted to create a tree with two pointer: one to blob with the text `f1` and the other `f2` and then I wanted to check it out to have two files. So probably you're right I'm not passing the string correctly to `mktree`, but I tried you variant with two files in one string to printf "100644 blob 8e1e71d5ce3... 100644 blob 9de77c" and got the same error.

Comment: I added an example using `printf`.

Comment: thanks, working great. so what is the correct syntax the `mktree` expects for multiple objects?

Comment: One line per entry (newline terminates entry), or one string per entry (NUL terminated) with `-z`, as [documented](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-mktree.html).

Comment: got it, thanks, actually the doc you linked doesn't explicitly define the syntax for multiple entries. just one more quick question - since commit references a tree and a branch references a commit I assume that git always eventually checks out a tree, correct?

Comment: (Yes, it's implied/implicit: you have to read the `git ls-tree` documentation and/or output. Though "NUL terminated" itself implies multiple entries, each with a NUL after it.) `git checkout` will handle a tree, but only in the "check out tree contents" form. It sort of "prefers" commits, which in the `git checkout <hash>` form become the *current* (HEAD) commit as a detached HEAD, or even-more-preferred, branch names, in the `git checkout <name>` form, which become the current branch as a non-detached ("attached"?) HEAD.

Comment: Note that a branch name can always be resolved to a commit hash (try, e.g., `git rev-parse master`) and the commit itself contains a (as in *exactly one*) `tree` line (try `git cat-file -p master`). So given a valid branch name, that name become the current branch and the commit is its value; given a name that's not a valid branch name but which can become a hash ID, that hash ID becomes the current commit; in either case the corresponding `tree` object gets copied into the index and work-tree.

Comment: got it, thanks a lot for you explanation, good luck! I also created [another question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/387105/90372) regarding `printf` that you used, if you have time take a look