# How do I "extract" a tree-ish to a directory?

Tags: git

I have an application that accepts git tree object hashes as input, and needs to extract those trees to a temporary directory.

Today, we do this by: ([morally](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg-tool/blob/1f792fe344171282bb16018755f86063cdbdf784/src/vcpkg/vcpkgpaths.cpp#L1102-L1129))

```
mkdir -p temporary/directory
cd temporary/directory
git archive --format tar f6ad2c912329ae4108883b8b8e20f2c50e968466 --output throwaway.tar.gz
tar xf throwaway.tar.gz
rm throwaway.tar.gz
```

Is there a way to ask git to extract/checkout the tree-ish directly rather than needing to create a throwaway tarball first?

Comment: Have you tried piping?

Comment: @eftshift0: piping is fine too (in addition to my answer); note that `git archive` can mess with the tree a bit, which can be a plus or a minus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given a Git repository in environment variable `$GIT_DIR` and an arbitrary but valid tree hash ID argument `$1`, running this in an empty directory:

```bash
#! /bin/sh
GIT_INDEX_FILE=$(mktemp) || exit 1
rm -f "$GIT_INDEX_FILE"
trap "rm -f $GIT_INDEX_FILE" 0 1 2 3 15

git read-tree -m -u $1
```

does the trick.  The `git read-tree` command reads the tree into the (non-existent because we removed it) temporary index file from `mktemp`, creating an index populated with that tree.  The `-m` flag (one of `-m`, `--reset`, or `--prefix` is required) enables the `-u` flag, which fills in the working tree, which is the current directory.

Add a bit of boilerplate to accept a Git repository argument and use `git --git-dir=$dir` to avoid having to export `GIT_DIR` into the above shell fragment.  The key command is `git read-tree` though.  You can also read the tree object and then use `git checkout-index`, but given `-u` there's no need for a second separate Git command.

Comment: Really, doesn't cleaning small tempfiles onesie-twosie seem like picking up every dust mote the moment it falls?  ``GIT_INDEX_FILE=`mktemp -u` git read-tree -um $1`` will do it, `$TMPDIR` gets cleaned out on reboot or on old-school setups via cron job.

Comment: @jthill: I don't clean out my `/tmp`, on purpose. Programs should clean up after themselves. (Also I have had machines stay up for multiple years in a row! The `-u` is handy though)

Comment: Finally got around to implementing this, thank you! https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg-tool/pull/1120